# How I can achieve this design using UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

[image]

Hi,

Can anybody have any sample code to create this view using UITableView in iOS.

Please help me out.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour.  Your question is too broad; you should have already attempted to solve the problem before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `UICollectionView` as it is more flexible and allows you to customise almost every part of it and also how the cells are arranged etc. To create the timetable/calendar layout you will need to create a custom FlowLayout.

There are libraries that do this exactly for you. This one, with some tweaking for your design, creates a calendar style collectionView :

https://github.com/erichoracek/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout

Hope this gives you a start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion